# Razor ASP.NET Core : Why the database connection status shows "Connecting" on first load and then on reload connects to the database successfully?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor, razor-pages

I am building a web application using the ASP.NET Core 3.1 MVC and Razor pages.

I am new to Razor pages.

I have created a registration page having following two fields -

1. User name (control type - text box)
2. User country (control type - drop down)

There is a button - **"Register"**

On running the application, the razor page is loaded but the Country drop down is **Empty**.

On refresh/reload of the same page, the Country drop down gets populated with the list of countries from the database.

On debugging, I found that on first run, the database connection  status shows ***"Connecting"*** and exception thrown is ***"ExecuteReader requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is connecting"***.

When the same page is refreshed/reloaded, the database connection status shows ***"Connected"*** and the drop down of country gets values.

**Question:**
**Why the database connection shows "Connecting" on first load of the razor page and then same page connects to the database successfully on refresh/reload?**

Following is the code snipptes for reference:

**Register.cshtml**

```
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label asp-for="@Model.UserCountry" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label"></label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <select asp-for="CountryId" asp-items="@Model.UserCountry">
                    <option value=""></option>
                </select>
                <span asp-validation-for="@Model.UserCountry" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
```

**Register.cshtml.cs**

```
        //
        [BindProperty]
        public int CountryId { get; set; }


        //Model definition    
        [BindProperty]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Country is required")]
        [Display(Name = "Country")]
        public List<SelectListItem> UserCountry
        {
            get
            {
                return FillList();
            }
        }

        //FillList retrieves country list from database
        public List<SelectListItem> FillList()
        {
            var list = new List<SelectListItem>();
            DataTable dtTableResult = new DataTable();
            try
            {
                objappdbcont = new AppDbContext();
                objappdbcont.ConnectionString = _configuration.GetSection("ConnectionStrings").GetSection("DefaultConnection").Value;
                dtTableResult = objappdbcont.GetLists();
                    foreach (DataRow row in dtTableResult.Rows)
                    {
                        list.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = row[0].ToString(), Text = row[1].ToString() });
                    }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                list.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = "0", Text = ex.Message.ToString() });
            }

            return list;
        }
```

**AppDBContect.cs**

```
    public DataTable GetLists()
    {

        SqlDataAdapter myAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
        DataSet myDataset = new DataSet();
        SqlDataReader myDataReader;
        DataTable dtTableResult = new DataTable();
        string strConnString = "";
        string storedprocname = "spGetCountries";
        
        try
        {
            strConnString = ConnectionString;

            using (SqlConnection connSrc1 = new SqlConnection(strConnString))
            {
                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand())
                {
                    myAdapter = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter();
                    command.Connection = connSrc1;
                    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    command.CommandTimeout = 0;
                    command.CommandText = storedprocname;
                    connSrc1.OpenAsync();
                    myDataReader = command.ExecuteReader();
                    dtTableResult.Load(myDataReader);
                    connSrc1.DisposeAsync();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var errmsg = ex.Message;
        }

        return dtTableResult;
    }
```

Comment: There are several issues with your code. When you're facing problems, start with something more simple. Skip db-stuff and see if you can make it working with hardcoded countries as a proof-of-concept. Good luck!

Comment: I corrected a mistake in the code snippet. I checked the code first with hardcoded countries list. Later I added database conn code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is solved by using **connSrc1.Open()** and "connSrc1.Dispose()" in place of **connSrc1.OpenAsync()** and "connSrc1.DisposeAsync()" respectively in the **GetLists()**
function of **AppDBContect.cs**.